# $().each(function() not getting proper dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, each

I have an existing table with data coming from the database inside `<input></input>`. If I want to click the Add button or press Enter key, it should append a new row.

Once I enter a data in the newly added row, I compare it with my existing array or previously added data on the same table. If there's an existing data in either my array or in the same table, the `<input></input>` shall remain empty until I enter a data that is unique and automatically appends a new row and so on.

Currently, only the first Enter keypress is working.

Here's my HTML:

```
<table id="datatable-boxes" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped forex-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Courier Tracking #</th>
            <th>Courier</th>
            <th>Vendor</th>
            <th width="20%">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" form="edit-boxes-form" class="form-control input-sm retrieve_track_no from_db" name="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]" id="retrieve_courier_tracking_no_1" value="4987176601285" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" form="edit-boxes-form" class="form-control input-sm from_db" name="retrieve_courier_name[]" id="retrieve_courier_name_1" value="Philpost" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" form="edit-boxes-form" class="form-control input-sm from_db" name="retrieve_vendor_name[]" id="retrieve_vendor_name_1" value="Ebay" /></td>
            <td class="box-action"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs clear-data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete Box data" data-target="#delete_box_modal_1"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My JS:

```
$(function(){
// GET ID OF last row and increment it by one - Edit Boxes
var $lastRetChar = 1, $newRetRow;
$get_lastRetID = function(){

    var str = $('#datatable-boxes tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("id");

    var index = str.lastIndexOf("_");
    var result = str.substr(index+1);

    var prev_char = $lastRetChar = parseInt(result);

    var courier_name = $('#retrieve_courier_name_'+prev_char).val();
    var vendor_name = $('#retrieve_vendor_name_'+prev_char).val();

    $lastRetChar = $lastRetChar + 1;
    $newRetRow = "<tr><td><input type='text' form='edit-boxes-form' class='form-control input-sm retrieve_track_no' name='retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]' id='retrieve_courier_tracking_no_"+$lastRetChar+"' autofocus='true'/></td><td><input form='edit-boxes-form' type='text' class='form-control input-sm' name='retrieve_courier_name[]' id='retrieve_courier_name_"+$lastRetChar+"' value='"+courier_name+"'/></td><td><input form='edit-boxes-form' type='text' class='form-control input-sm' name='retrieve_vendor_name[]' id='retrieve_vendor_name_"+$lastRetChar+"' value='"+vendor_name+"' /></td><td class='box-action'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs del_RetrieveBox'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete row'></span></button></td></tr>";

    return $newRetRow;
}
$('#datatable-boxes').on('keypress','input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]:last',function(e){
    console.log(this);
    $get_lastRetID();
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var seen = {};
        $('input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]').each(function() {
            var ret_txt = $(this).val();
            alert(ret_txt);
            found = findItem(boxes_array, ret_txt);
            if (seen[ret_txt] || found){
                if($(this).hasClass("from_db")){
                    checker = true;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $('.alert-batch-box-data').css('visibility', 'visible');
                    if(seen[ret_txt]){
                        $('.alert').append('<p class="text-left">You scanned <strong>'+ret_txt+'</strong> more than once.</p>');
                    }
                    if (found) {
                        $('.alert').append('<p class="text-left"><strong>'+ret_txt+'</strong> already exists in Batch # <strong>'+found.batch_no+'</strong>.</p>');
                    }
                    $(this).val('');
                    box_qty = parseInt($('#datatable-boxes tbody>tr').length);
                    $('#retrieve_box_qty').val(box_qty);
                    checker = false;
                    return false;
                }
            } else{
                if(ret_txt == ''){
                    alert('eto ata yun');
                    checker = false;
                    return false;
                }
                seen[ret_txt] = true;
                if($('#retrieve_courier_tracking_no_1').val() == ''){
                    $('#add_RetrieveBox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    $('#update_RetrieveBox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    checker = false;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    checker = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        if(checker == true){
            $('#datatable-boxes tbody').append($newRetRow);
            $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input.retrieve_track_no').focus();
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#retrieve_box_qty').val($lastRetChar);
            $('#add_RetrieveBox').css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('#update_RetrieveBox').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    }
});
//Append new row on edit boxes > receive
$('#add_RetrieveBox').on("click", function(){
        $get_lastRetID();
        $('#datatable-boxes tbody').append($newRetRow);
        $('#retrieve_box_qty').val($lastRetChar);
});

//Delete newly added row on frontend - Edit boxes-form
$('#datatable-boxes').on('click','tr .del_RetrieveBox',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $lastRetChar = $lastRetChar-1;
    $('#retrieve_box_qty').val($lastRetChar);
 });
});
```

When I tried to `alert()` the current value that's being called on the second row, it just calls the first row and then returns empty twice. Since empty already showed twice, it will return false so there will be no new row.

Example:

```
1st data = 4987176601285 (This is from the database)
2nd data = 123 (This is in frontend)
```

After hitting enter to have a 3rd row, the alerts are these:

```
4987176601285
*blank*
*blank*
eto na yun
```

I'm not sure why my newly entered data is not being picked up. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Provide an actual html example. Your php is useless for debugging front end. See [mcve]

Comment: Removed my PHP tags @charlietfl.

Comment: Apologies @wolfgang1983. They're a code snippet from my codeigniter site though?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `each()` function with `filter()`. I'm not entirely sure why this one worked and the other one did not.

```
$('#datatable-boxes input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]').filter(function() {
            value = $(this).val();
            ret_found = findItem(boxes_array, value);
            if (existing.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
                // console.log($(this).val());
                ret_checker = false;
                if(ret_found){
                    $('.alert-batch-box-data').css('display', 'visible');
                    $('.alert').append('<p class="text-left"><strong>'+value+'</strong> already exists in Batch # <strong>'+ret_found.batch_no+'</strong>.</p>');
                } else if((ret_checker == false) && (!ret_found)){
                    frontend_duplicate = true;
                    if($(this).val() == ''){
                        frontend_duplicate = false; 
                    }
                } else {
                    frontend_duplicate = false;
                }
                $(this).val('');
            } else {
                ret_checker = true;
                frontend_duplicate = false
            }
            existing.push(value);
        });
```

Then I modified it to fit with my previous code.